# Animation with Iteration over array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, animation

I try to construct an animated graph, using an iteration. I tried to adapt to the first example shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-animations-in-python/).

The idea is to let the graph grow with the number of entries. So the x-coordinates are an array of my data and the y-coordinates an array of 1s, so i.e.:
x = [100, 500, 300]
y = [1, 1, 1]

My animation starts, but seems to stop after two or three steps/frames.
My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# get and prepare dataframe
df_gas = pd.read_pickle('C:\\py_task\\pkl\\gas.pkl')
df_gas = df_gas.iloc[: , 1:]
df_gas['Leistung in kW'] = pd.to_numeric(df_gas['Leistung in kW'], errors='coerce')
df_gas = df_gas.sort_values(['Leistung in kW'])

#get array of values I want to show
df_gas_array = df_gas.to_numpy()

x = []
y = []

for i in df_gas_array:
    x.append(i)
    y.append(1)
    plt.xlim(0, 9200)
    plt.ylim(0, 23)
    plt.plot(x, y, color = 'green')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    
plt.show()
```

I use Python 3.7.9 with the IDE Thonny 3.3.13

Comment: You can try to change the argument of `plt.pause` sometimes a too small value can lead to this kind of issue

Comment: Changing the plt.pause argument unfortunately does not work